# Why is my RESTful WCF service so slow for LTE/4G connections?

Tags: iis, iis-8

I wrote a simple RESTful web service API using WCF 4.5 to exchange data with our iPhone application. The service is hosted at my office on a Windows 2012 Server with IIS 8.0 and is exposed externally through my company's domain (i.e. https://api.company.com/).

The issue that I am having is that when I access my API from a WiFi network on my phone I am seeing relatively fast response times (~1s) but when I access my API from my AT&T LTE connection the response times are brutally slow *most* of the time (~10-20s). According to http://www.speedtest.net, my download and upload speeds on LTE are actually *faster* than my WiFi connections.

I have performed my tests both in the office and away from the office. While at the office the WiFi network is on the same internal network as the server, but while at my home my WiFi network is not on the same network. I see the same ~1-2s response times on WiFi whether at home or in the office and I see the same ~10-20s response times on LTE in both locations.

I have enabled some logging on IIS to see reveal the individual requests with their response times. I changed my search query each time to ensure that the response wasn't being cached somewhere. I am only pulling back the first 100 records so the duration of the query should be about the same for any letter of the alphabet. The 50.x.x.x address is from my home WiFi and the 166.x.x.x address is from the LTE connection. The first request made on LTE actually timed out here and sited the sc-win32-status of 995 ([ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681388.aspx#ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)). This happens from time to time and I am not sure what the issue is there either or if it is related. One of the queries on LTE (q=j) took 3s.

```
#Fields: date time cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port c-ip sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-05-19 01:29:21 GET /v1/users q=a 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1762
2015-05-19 01:29:25 GET /v1/users q=b 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1060
2015-05-19 01:29:29 GET /v1/users q=c 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1060
2015-05-19 01:29:33 GET /v1/users q=e 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1294
2015-05-19 01:29:39 GET /v1/users q=e 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 3151
2015-05-19 01:29:44 GET /v1/users q=f 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1294
2015-05-19 01:30:11 GET /v1/users q=g 443 166.170.53.188 200 0 995 20156
2015-05-19 01:30:51 GET /v1/users q=h 443 166.170.53.188 200 0 0 19438
2015-05-19 01:30:59 GET /v1/users q=j 443 166.170.53.188 200 0 0 2979
2015-05-19 01:32:43 GET /v1/users q=k 443 166.170.53.188 200 0 0 23931
2015-05-19 01:32:57 GET /v1/users q=l 443 166.170.53.188 200 0 0 8502
2015-05-19 01:33:03 GET /v1/users q=m 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 2308
2015-05-19 01:33:06 GET /v1/users q=n 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1372
2015-05-19 01:33:11 GET /v1/users q=o 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1560
2015-05-19 01:33:16 GET /v1/users q=p 443 50.130.105.236 200 0 0 1419
```

I have tried configuring Failed Request Tracing in IIS for when the time-taken is > 5 seconds ([using this post](http://debugging.io/weblog/post/Debugging-hang-or-slow-response-in-your-production-aspnet-applications)). The longest duration in the event log was ~1s between AspNetHttpHandlerEnter and AspNetHttpHandlerLeave and I couldn't figure out why the requests were taking > 5 seconds on LTE.

### Additional Info

- The service is secured using HTTPS and basic authentication.
- The service uses Entity Framework 6.0 and SQL Server
- The payload is JSON and compressed using gzip
- The amount of data being transferred is less than 10kB
- The service is not currently using any async calls
- The service is being accessed very lightly at the moment (<500 calls per day)

Comment: Hi @tposchel, how is it going with this? We have an WCF that experiencing exactly the same issue, that it is so slow/timeout when client request using 4G LTE. It’s work fine if they connect to wifi. If anyone experienced the same please share an update or information is much appreciated.

Comment: @VuPham I honestly can't remember if this ever got resolved or not. I'm sorry!

Comment: Thank @TPoschel for your reply.